# Getting a Mod_Security error

Tags: wordpress, mod-security

When i install captcha plugin on my website and try to login, m getting Error:

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Comment: Check your web server logs, generally mod_security logs to your Apache logs location.